# If $f$ is even and $y'=f(y)$ then $y$ is odd

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

> Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ be an even function.
>
> Consider the maximal solution $y\colon\left]\alpha ,\beta\right[\to \mathbb{R}$ of the IVP $$y'=f(y),\ y(0)=0$$
>
> Prove that $y$ is an odd function and $\beta =-\alpha$.

To be able to prove that $y$ is odd, I first need its domain to be symmetric ($x\in \left]\alpha ,\beta\right[\implies -x\in \left]\alpha ,\beta\right[$), from here I can conclude that $\alpha=-\beta$. But how to prove the domain is symmetric?

And how to prove that $y(-x)=-y(x)$ for all $x\in \left]\alpha,\beta\right[$? I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the derivative of an even function is odd and $y'=f(y)$, but I can't see how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, $\alpha<0<\beta$.
Let $r=\min\{-\alpha,\beta\}$ so that we at least have a solution on $\left]-r,r\right[$.

Then show: If $y$ is a solution on $]\alpha,\beta[$, then $x\mapsto-y(-x)$ is a solution on $\left]-\beta,-\alpha\right[$.

By uniqueness, these coincide on $\left]-r,r\right[$.

Then you can combine $y$ with $x\mapsto- y(-x)$ to find a solution on $\left]-\max\{-\alpha,\beta\},\max\{-\alpha,\beta\}\right[$. By maximality, we conclude $\alpha=-\max\{\alpha,\beta\}=-\beta$.

Comment: Why does uniqueness hold?

Comment: @GitGud First of all, if it doesn't, the claim is false ;)

Comment: ^_^, thanks. Can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: @GitGud Of course not. As $f$ is $C^1$, it is Lipschitz and we optain uniqueness from Picard-Lindelöff.

Answer (score 1):

Define $h(x)=-y(-x)$. Then 
$$
h'(x)=y'(-x)=f(y(-x))=f(-h(x))=f(h(x)),
$$
where we have used the eveness of $f$. Now, notice that $h(0)=-y(0)=0=y(0)$. As the solution should be unique you obtain that $y$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little problem in the formulation of this question.

In order to even wonder whether $\alpha=\beta$, a further piece of information is necessary: *That the solution is defined in a maximum possible domain.*

Clearly, if the flux function (here $f$) satisfies conditions which guarantee uniqueness (which here it does as $f$ is $C^1$, and thus locally uniformly Lipschitz continuous), then it is possible to talk about a "solution defined in a maximum open interval". This is obtained as the set-theoretic union of all solutions of this particular IVP; these solutions do not have the same domain, but each two of them agree in their common domain due to uniqueness. (Note that a function, in Set Theory, is defined as a set on ordered pairs.) If uniqueness is not enjoyed by an IVP, then we simply talk about a "solution defined in a maximal interval", and apparently its definition requires the use of Zorn's  lemma.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here, for someone that has a similar question.

Since f is odd, y' = f(y)=f(-y) — This means that not only the function is odd, but f[y(t)]=f[-y(t)] (we'll get to this later)

From this, we come to the point that y(t) has a known point (0,0) , from the inicial condition.

Let us consider a point α :

f[y(α)] = y'(α) = f[-y(α)]

Considering now α and -α=β, we come to :

f[y(α)] = y' = f[-y(-α)] =f[-y(β)]

This means that f[y(α)] = f[-y(β)] = f[-y(-α)]

This implies that y(α) = -y(-α) , condition for a odd function f(x) = -f(-x) , so y(t) is odd, and it's done.

Comment: The few true statements about symmetry have already been made in previous answers, as they are the basis of them. Manipulations of the derivative values at discrete points does not prove any claim on the solution of the differential equation.